# linear transformation of a line problem

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I am studying maths as a hobby and have tried the following question.

Find the equation of the line $\frac{x+3}{-2} = \frac{y-1}{4}$ after it has been transformed using $\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

I have said

$\frac{x+3}{-2} = \frac{y-1}{4} = k\\
x=-2k-3\\
y=4k+1\\
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-2k -3\\
4k+1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-6k -9\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
-4k -1\\
8k+2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-10k -10\\
8k+2
\end{pmatrix}\\
k=\frac{x+10}{-10}=\frac{y-2}{8}\\
\rightarrow \frac{x+10}{-10}=\frac{y-2}{8}$

But the textbook says the answer is

$\frac{x+10}{-5}=\frac{y-2}{2}$

Have I made a mistake or is the textbook wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also solve this problem by first finding two points lying on the line given by $\dfrac{x+3}{2} =\dfrac{y-1}{4}$, for instance, $A=(-2.5, 0)$ and $B=(0, -5)$. Let us now apply the given transformation to obtain the coordinates of the two corresponding points lying on the given line after it has been transformed.
$$A_t = \left(\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-2.5 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-7.5 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right) $$

$$B_t = \left(\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-5\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
5 \\
-10 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)\quad $$

The equation of the line that contains the points $A_t=\left(-7.5,0\right)$ and $B_t=\left(5,-10\right)$ is
$$5y+4x =-30,$$ which tallies with your answer.

Comment: Thank you.  A most helpful explanation.

Comment: You are welcome